# Como almacenar valor en celda y mostrarla con un boton

Tags: php

Tengo una tabla que relleno desde una consulta a la base. Recibo los registros que necesito mediante un while y en la ultima columna de la tabla ubico un botón. La idea es que cuando clickeo ese boton pueda visualizar un modal con los datos del campo 'COMENTA' , el cual durante el bucle voy guardando en la variable $comentario.
Obtengo correctamente los registros, pude hacer funcionar el modal , pero me falta como mostrar la información.
Copio el código :

```html
<html>
<head>
    <Link href="estilo1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function vw_mostrar() {
        document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
    }

    function vw_nomostrar() {
        document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="fade" class="overlay"></div>
  <div id="light" class="modal">
     <p>TEXTO DE EJEMPLO O PRUEBAS JAJDJDJDJDJDJDJD </p>
     <p><input type='button' value='Leído' id='Ver' onclick="javascript:vw_nomostrar();"</p>
  </div>
<p><a href="javascript:vw_mostrar();">Ver</a></p>
</body>

<div id="contiene_tabla">
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nº SOCIO</th>
        <th>INGRESA</th>
        <th>NOMBRES Y APELLIDO</th>
        <th>CATEGORIA</th>
        <th>PUNTOS</th>
        <th> ? </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<?php

require('controlador.php');

    $consulta1 = socios_alerta($conS,$cadena_nueva);

        while ($fila = oci_fetch_array($consulta1, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

        $vsocio=trim($fila['NUM_SOCIO']);
        $vfecha=trim($fila['FECHA']);
        $vapellido=trim($fila['APELLIDO']);
        $vnombre=trim($fila['NOMBRE']);
        $vcate=trim($fila['CATEGORIA']);
        $vpuntaje=trim($fila['PUNTOS']);
        $comentario=trim($fila['COMENTA']);

        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "    <td align='center'>" . $vsocio . "</td>\n";
        echo "    <td align='right'>" . $vfecha . "</td>\n";
        echo "    <td align='left'>"  . $vnombre . ", " . $vapellido . "</td>\n";
        echo "    <td align='center'>" . $vcate . "</td>\n";
        echo "    <td align='right'>" . $vpuntaje ."</td>\n";
        echo "    <td align='center'><input type='button' value='Ver' id='Ver' onclick='javascript:vw_mostrar()';></td>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n";
        
        }
        
        oci_close($conn);

?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

La página es en PHP y uso algo de html.

Comment: que es lo que quiere que se muestre en `<p>TEXTO DE EJEMPLO O PRUEBAS JAJDJDJDJDJDJDJD </p>` cuando haces click en ver?

Answer (score 1):

Estimado, esta sería una opción:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <Link href="estilo1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function vw_mostrar(comentario) {
        document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('comentario').innerHTML = comentario;
    }

    function vw_nomostrar() {
        document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="fade" class="overlay"></div>
  <div id="light" class="modal">
     <p id="comentario">TEXTO DE EJEMPLO O PRUEBAS JAJDJDJDJDJDJDJD </p>
     <p><input type='button' value='Leído' id='Ver' onclick="javascript:vw_nomostrar();"</p>
  </div>
<p><a href="javascript:vw_mostrar();">Ver</a></p>
</body>

<div id="contiene_tabla">
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nº SOCIO</th>
        <th>INGRESA</th>
        <th>NOMBRES Y APELLIDO</th>
        <th>CATEGORIA</th>
        <th>PUNTOS</th>
        <th> ? </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<?php

require('controlador.php');

    $consulta1 = socios_alerta($conS,$cadena_nueva);

        while ($fila = oci_fetch_array($consulta1, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

        $vsocio=trim($fila['NUM_SOCIO']);
        $vfecha=trim($fila['FECHA']);
        $vapellido=trim($fila['APELLIDO']);
        $vnombre=trim($fila['NOMBRE']);
        $vcate=trim($fila['CATEGORIA']);
        $vpuntaje=trim($fila['PUNTOS']);
        $comentario=trim($fila['COMENTA']);

        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "    <td align='center'>" . $vsocio . "</td>\n";
        echo "    <td align='right'>" . $vfecha . "</td>\n";
        echo "    <td align='left'>"  . $vnombre . ", " . $vapellido . "</td>\n";
        echo "    <td align='center'>" . $vcate . "</td>\n";
        echo "    <td align='right'>" . $vpuntaje ."</td>\n";
        echo "    <td align='center'><input type=\"button\" value=\"Ver\" id=\"Ver\" onclick=\"javascript:vw_mostrar('".$comentario."')\";></td>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n";
        
        }
        
        oci_close($conn);

?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Buenísimo !!!! un solo tema , cuando traigo mas de 2 lineas de texto no ejecuta , no sale la ventana modal , se te ocurre que puede ser ?

Comment: O sea, si $comentario=trim($fila['COMENTA']); Trae texto de mas de 2 filas ( es un varchar(1000)) , no se muestra la ventana modal, si le saco texto hasta aprox. 120 caracteres , si se muestra ...

Comment: Claro, ese será un problema, ya que como estamos pasando el texto como variable y este texto tiene escapes de lineas (saltos), dará un error. Lo optimo quizas sería que en el parametro fuera un ID del registro y que el script tomara este ID lo consulte, asincrono, y solo traiga el valor de comentario.

Comment: Otra opción es dejar en un div oculto el valor de $comentario con un identificador unico por fila, entonces cuando llames la variable este consulte el texto del contenedor y lo muestre en el modal. Necesitas un ejemplo?

Comment: Si claro, a ver si puedo entenderlo e incorporarlo

Comment: algo que no comprendo, y claro debe tener un motivo concreto, si hablamos de saltos, por que razón no me funcionaría un str_replace en el string antes de pasarlo al javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Tenía que resolver este tema y lo resolvía mediante ajax , tuve que cambiar gran parte del código por ello no lo cito, pero creo es la forma indicada. Por supuesto agradezco la ayuda recibida, me hizo aprender un poco más y razonar la solución.

Comment: excelente, disculpa no tuve tiempo de hacer un ejemplo más amplio.